# Login with facebook PHP OAuth client error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-php-sdk

I'm working with Facebook login on my website:

```
<?php
/*
 * login_with_facebook.php
 */

    require('http.php');
    require('oauth_client.php');

    $client = new oauth_client_class;
    $client->debug = false;
    $client->debug_http = true;
    $client->server = 'Facebook';
    $client->redirect_uri = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].
        dirname(strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?')).'/login_with_facebook.php';

    $client->client_id = ''; $application_line = __LINE__;
    $client->client_secret = '';

    if(strlen($client->client_id) == 0
    || strlen($client->client_secret) == 0)
        die('Please go to Facebook Apps page https://developers.facebook.com/apps , '.
            'create an application, and in the line '.$application_line.
            ' set the client_id to App ID/API Key and client_secret with App Secret');

    /* 
     * API permissions
     */
    $client->scope = 'email';
    if(($success = $client->Initialize()))
    {
        if(($success = $client->Process()))
        {
            if(strlen($client->access_token))
            {
                $success = $client->CallAPI(
                    'https://graph.facebook.com/me', 
                    'GET', array(), array('FailOnAccessError'=>true), $user);
            }
        }
        $success = $client->Finalize($success);
    }
    if($client->exit)
        exit;
    if($success)
    {
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook OAuth client results</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
        echo '<h1>', HtmlSpecialChars($user->name), 
            ' you have logged in successfully with Facebook!</h1>';
        echo '<pre>', HtmlSpecialChars(print_r($user, 1)), '</pre>';
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    }
    else
    {
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>OAuth client error</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>OAuth client error</h1>
<pre>Error: <?php echo HtmlSpecialChars($client->error); ?></pre>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    }

?>
```

When I hit "Login with Facebook" on the example site, I get this error after logging into Facebook;

OAuth client error

Error: it was not possible to open the OAuth access token URL: 111 could not connect to the host "graph.facebook.com"

The Facebook App is setup and live, with correct Client ID and Client secret Keys, MySQL queries setup.

Any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: That sounds like your server does either not allow your script to connect to FB servers, or something is configured wrong in that regard. Ask your server admin.

Comment: Why aren't you using the Facebook PHP SDK? The issue is likely to do with the SSL certificate. If the oauth library is using cUrl, set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false.